# I want to format a number as a percent using Python string formatting expressions but it fails

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7.3

```
>>> print '%2.2f' % 0.1
0.10
```

The documentation I have says that type % should be the same as type f except that the input is multiplied by 100.

```
>>> print '%2.2%' % 0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the new format expression, which has the formatter you are referring to

```
print "{:%}".format(0.1)
#10.000000%
```

if you just want the integer part you can use the precision specification

```
print "{:.0%}".format(0.1)
#10%
```

see the doc at

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string#formatspec

To expand a little bit, the new format specificator is really more powerful than the old one. First of all it's really simple calling the parameters by order or name

```
"play the {instrument} all {moment}, even if my {instrument} is old".format(moment='day', instrument='guitar')
#'play the guitar all day, even if my guitar is old'
```

then, as can be seen in the documentation, is possible to have access to properties of the object:

```
"the real component is {0.real} and the imaginary one is {0.imag}".format(3+4j)
#'the real component is 3.0 and the imaginary one is 4.0'
```

There is a lot more than this, but you can find it all in the documentation, that is very clear.

Comment: Absolutely, the new format specification is way better than the other...even if I kinda miss the % operator for the string substitution...

Comment: I actually always thought the ``%`` operator on strings was horribly unclear and arbitrary, I much prefer the ``format()`` method which is more obvious.

Comment: Yeah, it is unclear and arbitrary, no discussion on that, it's just a bad habit of mine. The really good thing (IMHO) about the format function is that it connect the meaning very well with the \_\_format\_\_magic method.

Comment: It's legacy code so I was hoping just to tweak a fairly long string.

Comment: how much legacy are we talking about? the string format function is available only after python 2.6. Normally it's not a problem since most OS ship version 2.6 or after, but is this your case? In any case, you can tweak a string complex at will, I will edit to explain more, ok?

Answer (score 4):

Came across this question. In Python 3 you can simply use fstrings (thus avoiding the `.format`) in a similar way as described above. The format is:

```
print(f"{your_number:.n_decimals%}")
```

Eg.

```
>>> print(f"{0.0350:.2%}")
3.50%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print '%2.2%' % 0.1
```

Tells it that there are 2 placeholders in format string (%), so you have a complain